# How 20q. works?

Tags: web-applications, web

How does the web app http://20q.net work? Can I write a similar program, in a smaller scale, and if yes how?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, this is called an "expert system" and can be represented by a binary tree (in the case of yes/no questions only). Each non-leaf node in your tree is a question (e.g. *Is it a mammal?*). Each leaf is a final answer (e.g. *Giraffe*) with an implied question *Is it a giraffe?*. If the answer to this final question is yes, the user guessed the answer. If the answer is no, then the user should be prompted to input a new question (added to the database) where the answer is yes for the new answer (e.g. *wombat*) and no for the old answer (*giraffe*). The system grows in "intelligence" the more it is used.

Comment: Thanks.. will definitely attempt to write one of these programs.

Comment: Ahh the good ol' 20 questions exercise. Reminds me of late nights in the computer lab.